# Using Variable in XPath expression with input elements having prefixes

Tags: xml, variables, xslt, xpath

I have 3 employee records as below. In my XSLT I have created a variable with line numbers 1, 2, & 3 and then looping through each of these lines to print fname. But it is not working.

Below is the input xml:

```
<tns:empLines>
    <tns:empLine>
        <can:fname>John</can:fname>
        <can:lname>Doe</can:lname>
        <can:age>20</can:age>
        <can:lineNumber>1</can:lineNumber>
    </tns:empLine>
    <tns:empLine>
        <can:fname>James</can:fname>
        <can:lname>Douglas</can:lname>
        <can:age>24</can:age>
        <can:lineNumber>2</can:lineNumber>
    </tns:empLine>
    <tns:empLine>
        <can:fname>Joe</can:fname>
        <can:lname>Sims</can:lname>
        <can:age>30</can:age>
        <can:lineNumber>3</can:lineNumber>
    </tns:empLine>
</tns:empLines>
```

Below is my xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="lines">
            <line num="1"/>
            <line num="2"/>
            <line num="3"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <root>
            <xsl:for-each select="$lines/line">
                <pc>
                    <xsl:value-of select="//*[local-name()='empLines']/*[local-name()='empLine'][*[local-name()='lineNumber']=current()/@num]/*[local-name()='fname']/text()"/>
                </pc>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: What does "it is not working" mean? Are you getting an error message or garbage printed?

Comment: **1.** That cannot be your input: the prefixes must be declared and bound to a namespace. **2.** You cannot loop over a variable defined that way, because it's not a *node-set*. I am not sure why you can't loop over the empLines instead: what is the result you are trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 2):

In XSLT 1.0, the `lines` variable you showed contains a result tree fragment instead of a node-set, and therefore it can't be used before a `/` in an XPath, as in `$lines/line`. There are a few ways around this.

1. Use XSLT 2.0.
2. Use a `node-set()` extension function (not universally portable) to convert $lines into a node-set.
3. Make the content of `$lines` a top-level element in the stylesheet, like this:

-

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:foo="foo">

  <foo:lines>
    <line num="1"/>
    <line num="2"/>
    <line num="3"/>
  </foo:lines>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="lines" select="document('')/foo:lines" />
    <root>
      <xsl:for-each select="$lines/line"> ...
```

Note that the top-level element must be in a namespace other than the xsl one.

However, michael is quite right that the XML input you showed is not well-formed (in regard to namespaces). That should be giving you an error.